# Why is this migration not migrating on mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I am integrating a CAS client using [rack-cas gem](https://github.com/biola/rack-cas) on an application using mysql database, When i run,

`rails generate cas_session_store_migration` as specified on the readme, it generates a migration `20140428130031_create_rack_cas_sessions.rb` which looks like this:

```
class CreateRackCasSessions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :sessions do |t|
      t.string :session_id, :null => false
      t.string :cas_ticket
      t.text :data
      t.timestamps
    end

   add_index :sessions, :session_id
   add_index :sessions, :cas_ticket
   add_index :sessions, :updated_at
 end

 def self.down
   drop_table :sessions
 end
end
```

when i run `rake db:migrate` or `bundle exec rake db:migrate` nothing happens. The migration fails to take place and there is no error message(s). The same migration on another service using sqlite database migrates successfully.

Comment: Is your DB configuration pointing at your MySQL database instance and not your SQLite database instance?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll the DB configuration for the development environment is configured to use MySQL database.

Comment: Ok, figured it was worth asking since you said it runs fine against your SQLite database.

Comment: Maybe you have already run such migration and migration version is in `schema_migrations` table. Try to run `rake db:migrate:redo` (if it fails with with message "can't drop table" - comment temporary line `drop_table :sessions`)

Comment: Does your migration show up in the schema_migrations table?

Comment: @UriMikhli no, the migration is not in the schema_migrations table.

Comment: try to generate another migration (just to test) and check if it works

Comment: @patte what does --trace say when you run rake --trace db:migrate? This feels like something I've seen before where you dont have permissions to create the table but I cant remember the details.

Comment: @UriMikhli This is the result of `rake --trace db:migrate`         `** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump`

Comment: @gotva I have tried generating another migration but the results are the same.

Comment: I have finally found the problem. For some reason, the migration generated by `rails generate cas_session_store_migration` did not have a file extension. The generated migration was `20140428130031_create_rack_cas_sessions` and not `20140428130031_create_rack_cas_sessions.rb`. as i thought and even misleadingly put it in the question. This only happens specifically on this application. On other applications the generator generates the migration with the file extension. I guess i'll have to put up a new question to get the explanation for that

Comment: I just merged a [pull request](https://github.com/biola/rack-cas/pull/16) from [nirnanaaa](https://github.com/nirnanaaa) and released [version 0.9.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-cas/versions/0.9.1) that fixes this issue. Thanks.